# How to authenticate Openfire XMPP with JWT token instead of username, password

Tags: authentication, jwt, xmpp, openfire

I use Openfire for my chat server. In NestJS application server is used for authentication. While user registers, a XMPP account is also created using Openfire REST API plugin. I am using JWT authentication with my backend code.

What I want is when a user logs in the my application, it has to be automatically connected to XMPP server from web client using JWT. Is it possible to achieve this with JWT or any other suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](https://www.surekhatech.com/blog/openfire-custom-authentication-with-liferay) . I myself am implementing jwt authentication. I am following this link.